Terraform - How to use same resource creation code block for multiple role assignments
I am sure there is a better way to achieve it hence I thought to ask it here. Currently I am creating PIM role assignment (both active and eligible) in a different resource block for each of the default roles in Azure. e.g. Data Factory Contributor, Grafana Editor and many others.
I would like to compress the code for each resource creation block and also variables block if possible so that I am not duplicating same code again and again for each of the role assignment.
Can someone please help with their expertise on Terraform to achieve this? I don't want to over complicate it as well so if its simple, I would like to go for it.
//azurerm_role_definition code block
data "azurerm_role_definition" "roles" {
  for_each = toset(["Data Factory Contributor", "Grafana Editor"])
  name     = each.value
}

variable "groupids_data_factory_contributor" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["387400af-3a87-4ee6-ac9b-487283203ecb", "d5ad0c72-5c44-422a-bd2f-7261a1415ed1"]
}
variable "groupids_grafana_editor" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["387400af-3a87-4ee6-ac9b-487283203ecb", "875a79c6-26dc-4402-a9f4-7a18e3fbde0e"]
}

resource "azurerm_pim_active_role_assignment" "data_factory_contributor" {
  for_each = toset(var.groupids_data_factory_contributor)
  scope              = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_id = "${data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id}${data.azurerm_role_definition.roles["Data Factory Contributor"].id}"
  principal_id       = each.value
  schedule {
    start_date_time = time_static.example.rfc3339
    expiration {
      duration_hours = 8
    }
  }
  ticket {
    number = "1"
    system = "blank"
  }
  justification = "Expiration Duration Set"
}

resource "azurerm_pim_active_role_assignment" "grafana_editor" {
  for_each = toset(var.groupids_grafana_editor)
  scope              = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_id = "${data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id}${data.azurerm_role_definition.roles["Grafana Editor"].id}"
  principal_id       = each.value
  schedule {
    start_date_time = time_static.example.rfc3339
    expiration {
      duration_hours = 8
    }
  }
  ticket {
    number = "1"
    system = "blank"
  }
  justification = "Expiration Duration Set"
}

I am expecting the code to be compressed into single resource creation block so that I am not duplicating it for each role assignment.

Yes, you could join your two lists into a single list, adding the role_definition_id in a new field.

@LorenzoFelletti - Thanks for your comment. Not too sure what you mean by adding the role_definition_id in a new field. Can you please show a sample that I can follow?


Using same resource creation code block for multiple role assignments using terraform.

Here to achieve this we can use 'for_each' and 'locals' to avoid duplication for each role assignment.
As Lorenzo Felletti suggested we can use role_definition_id in the new field. Define the roles you want to assign in the local map and by using dynamic modules in azurerm_pim_active_role_assignment
The code which I shared below uses the single resource block for multiple role assignments.
Terraform code :
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {}

data "azurerm_role_definition" "roles" {
  for_each = toset(["Data Factory Contributor", "Grafana Editor"])
  name     = each.value
}

variable "role_assignments" {
  type = map(list(string))
  default = {
    "Data Factory Contributor" = ["733f2806-xxx-b59af3b21126", "ea5ab011-xxx-ed2350d96cc4"]
    "Grafana Editor"           = ["733f2806-xxx-b59af3b21126", "ea5ab011-xxx-ed2350d96cc4"]
  }
}

resource "time_static" "example" {
  rfc3339 = "2023-06-18T00:00:00Z"
}

locals {
  combined_assignments = flatten([
    for role, ids in var.role_assignments : [
      for id in ids : {
        role_definition_id = data.azurerm_role_definition.roles[role].id
        principal_id       = id
        role               = role
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "existing" {
  for_each = { for idx, val in local.combined_assignments : idx => val }

  scope              = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_name = each.value.role
  principal_id       = each.value.principal_id

  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
  depends_on = [
    data.azurerm_subscription.primary
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_pim_active_role_assignment" "assignments" {
  for_each = { for idx, val in local.combined_assignments : idx => val }

  scope              = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_id = each.value.role_definition_id
  principal_id       = each.value.principal_id

  schedule {
    start_date_time = time_static.example.rfc3339
    expiration {
      duration_hours = 8
    }
  }
  
  ticket {
    number = "1"
    system = "blank"
  }
  
  justification = "Expiration Duration Set"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
    ignore_changes        = [justification]
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "10m"
    delete = "10m"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_role_assignment.existing
  ]
}

Deployment succeeded:




thanks @vinay-b for detailed response. Yes your code did work for me as well. One think that didn't work was azurerm_role_assignment block and I removed it since it was failing to create with incorrect Type error since the Ids in my case are Group Ids. What's the reason of having that additional resource type if what we are trying to do is covered with azurerm_pim_active_role_assignment?

The azurerm_role_assignment resource was mistakenly used to check existing assignments, causing errors with group IDs remove that part. Instead, focus only on the azurerm_pim_active_role_assignment resource. Ensure role assignments are idempotent by manually validating the state before applying changes. @ankurkapoor
